# Why is my href generating # in the url in Django Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I am new to *Django*.
I am using an HTML template for making a sidebar. Whenever I click on the sub-menu button URL is generated with a *#* e.g *http://localhost:8000/#form*
. When removing # manually *forms* works fine.

here is my *HTML* code:

```
<!-- ========== Left Sidebar Start ========== -->
        
        <div class="vertical-menu">

            <div data-simplebar class="h-100">

                <!--- Sidemenu -->
                <div id="sidebar-menu">
                    <!-- Left Menu Start -->
                    <ul class="metismenu list-unstyled" id="side-menu">
                        <li class="menu-title">Main</li>


                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="waves-effect">
                                <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-primary float-end">20+</span>
                                <i class="mdi mdi-view-dashboard"></i>
                                <span> Dashboard </span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                                <li><a href="index.html">Dashboard One</a></li>
                                <li><a href="form">Form</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="widgets.html" class="waves-effect">
                                <i class="mdi mdi-cube-outline"></i>
                                <span> Widgets </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>

.
.
.
```

here is my urls.py code:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('form', views.form, name="form"),
]
```

here is my views.py code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})

def form(request):
    return render(request, 'form.html', {})
```

Comment: You should be using the [url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Comment: using href="{% url 'form'  %}" is generating http://localhost:8000/#/form

Comment: I would say you have some javascript modifying your anchor tags, which you haven't shown in your question.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Can you please tell me where to look for it, so that I can check the code.

Comment: I think, that you have to use django routing links, not filenames (index.html) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/

Answer (score 0):

In your html file you need to make the links to index and form as follows:

```
                            <ul class="sub-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                                <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Dashboard One</a></li>
                                <li><a href="{% url 'form' %}">Form</a></li>
```

A minimum working example is below.

Folder structure:

[image]

`manage.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "doodle.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

`settings.py`

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'a'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = '127.0.0.1', 'localhost'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'doodle_app',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'doodle.urls'

TEMPLATES = [{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'doodle_app', 'templates'),],
},]
```

`urls.py` (in folder `doodle`)

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.urls import path

from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('doodle_app.urls')),
]
```

`form.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <h1>In Form</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Dashboard One</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'form' %}">Form</a></li>
  </ul>
</html>
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <h1>In index</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Dashboard One</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url 'form' %}">Form</a></li>
  </ul>
</html>
```

`urls.py` [in folder `doodle_app`]

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('form', views.form, name="form"),
]
```

and finally `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {})

def form(request):
    return render(request, 'form.html', {})
```

pip install the Django environment and run: `python manage.py runserver` open a browser and enter `localhost:8000` ...

Comment: using href="{% url 'form' %}" is generating localhost:8000/#/form

Comment: That should not be ... I have a minimum working example and that just works fine. I will add to my answer